# Restored Backup Not Showing Up, Didn't Use Minecraft's Built-in Feature

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

When backing up my world, I copied the complete save file instead of using Minecraft's built in feature. I pasted it in the save file (on my new computer, so the original world wasn't there), but it refuses to show up in the worlds.

Here is the folder path I’m using:

```
C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\Dunno
```

Comment: We’ll need more information from you to deduce your problem. What was the file name/path of the file you copied, and to what folder oath did you copy it to?

Comment: the name of the world file is simply the world name, and it is copied to the saves file.

Comment: What was the file oath of the file you copied?

Comment: What do you mean "file oath" mean?

Comment: File path. Sorry, typo

Comment: C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\Dunno

Comment: Are you copying the entire folder, or just a file within that folder?

Comment: the entire folder.